# WP adding extra menu button on refres

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've added a menu to my custom WP theme, which all is good with. However, when I refresh the page, SOMETIMES an extra blank title in the menu shows up before all of them. Is there a fix to this? Did I do something wrong?

Here is a image of what I am talking about:

[image]

```
<div id="navbar">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Primary Menu', 'container' => false,'menu_id' => 'main-nav','depth'=>'2')); ?>
        <div id="login" >
    <?php if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){ ?>               
    <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">

        <input value="Username" class="input" type="text" tabindex="10" name="log" id="user_login" style="padding-left: 2px;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Username') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" />
        <input value="Password" class="input" type="password" tabindex="20" name="pwd" id="user_pass" style="padding-left: 2px;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" />
        <input name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" tabindex="100" value=" " type="submit" class="loginbutton" >
        <input name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>" type="hidden">
        <input name="testcookie" value="1" type="hidden">

</form>
            <a class="helpbutton" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword"></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <ul class="admin_box">
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-admin/post-new.php">Write New Post</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/forums">Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('$index.php'); ?>">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    <?php }?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it random that the empty menu entry appears, or on a specific page?

Comment: It's random. Can happen on any page.

Comment: You have extra <a></a> tags appearing from <!-- Begin Header --> on down in your screenshot. I actually think your problem is starting in your <div id="header"> block. Check for any <a> links in there without a terminating </a> tag.

Comment: just went through to check it. All <a> tags have a terminating tag as well... Could it be something with the functions or css?

Comment: CSS doesn't write empty <a> tags into your document, and your navigation function looks syntactically correct. Can you post your header block either here, or on jsfiddle?